# Angularjs Translate with json file comments

Tags: angularjs, internationalization

It is possible to use json comments to organize language files?
I created a plunkr example with the error on browser console "SyntaxError: Unexpected token /"

```
{
 "HEADLINE": "Hello there!", /* COMMENT*/
 "LANG_DE_DE": "Lang: German", 
 "LANG_EN_US": "Lang: English"
}
```

[plunkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/83tjoh7t48204TfvY2rc?p=preview)

Comment: No can't do like this.

Comment: There is no way to comment json. If you want to comment, add a "comment" to the object

Comment: thank you I have to find another way to organize labels on the same file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since the file has to be valid JSON and JSON does not provide any comments in its syntax: No, you can not add comments there. It's against the specification of JSON, sorry.

Comment: thank you I have to find another way to organize labels on the same file